# BigQuery UI when logged into multiple Google Accounts

Tags: google-bigquery

Not the most pressing problem facing humanity at the moment, but a frequent if minor annoyance:

When using Google BigQuery, you can only seem to use the default Google Account that your browser is logged into. Currently when I need to use BQ from a browser, I have to start an incognito window and log in using my secondary Google Account. This is unlike any other Google service (cloud or not); generally I can switch accounts in the top right.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not implemented yet in Web UI!

See respective issue tracker - [`Multilogin Support`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905302)

Quotes from link:

> We don't yet have a version of the BQ UI in Pantheon that is far enough along to be a solution to this problem. We hope to have a version ready to try out this summer, but it may not be feature-complete even then.
>
> In the meantime I'd recommend using Chrome profiles (or equivalent in your browser of choice) to switch users rather than using multilogin. Or, if you still want to use multilogin and you have only one account that you use BQ with, make it your primary multilogin account (i.e., sign out of everything else and sign in to that account first).

Comment: To update this: multiple-account support landed in the [beta BigQuery UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) much earlier this year, and works like most Google services. Click on your profile photo in the top right -> change accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late, but the problem still persists.
Firefox(quantum) users(afaik from v57) can open color coded container tabs. This way you can have multiple (default) google sessions per tabs/tab groups. That solves not only BQ, but also google product problems
[colored container tab groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vh36.jpg)